# How to make the android code to execute the next line of code in a method, only after current line referred method has been completed?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I create an object of a class from that sdk and now I have to call two methods - initialise (type void and ASYNCHRONOUS METHOD) and getParameters. But, I have to make sure that getParameters is called only after the initialise method has been completed and the value of `INTENT_INITIALISATION_ACTION` has changed. I know I am supposed to use the broadcast receiver to do this, but how do I make the code work in the desired order. Adding some dummy code here

```
class Helper {

    SDK obj = new SDK();

    public void initialise(Context context) {
        obj.initialise(context);
    }

    public Params getParams() {
        return obj.getParameters();
    }

}
```

Here is a helper class communicating with the sdk and below is the class which is calling the methods.

```
class Bridge {

    Helper helper = new Helper();

    public Params getParams () {

        helper.initialise(context);

        return helper.getParams();
        
    }

}
```

What is currently happening is that, after hitting the `helper.initialise(context)` method, it jumps to the `helper.getParams()` while the initialise method had not been completed and the getParams method thus returns null and the initialise method eventually gets completed. But I want `helper.getParams()` to be called only after the completion of the initialise method.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is not happening.  Code is executed on a thread sequentially.  helper.getParams() will not be called until helper.initialize() returns.  There are only 2 situations where something that could look like that but are actually different issues could occur though:

1. initialize calls getParams, either directly or indirectly (something it calls call it).  The way to fix that is for you to eliminate that call.
2. initialize starts a thread to do something asynchronously and returnsIn this case initialize did return.  Its just doing asynchronous work.  In this case, initialize should take a callback and you should only call getParams in the callback.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The thing is, that the integrated SDK is readOnly and I cannot make any change to the initialise method that is already implemented in the SDK. I know that initialise method changes ```INTENT_INITIALIZATION_ACTION``` and I can create a broadcastReceiver to catch that change. But how to make sure getParams method is called only after the onReceive method of broadcast receiver was called

Answer (score -1):

If you want to wait for an event to happen before you do something, you must  implement observer pattern. One of the ways to implement observer pattern is by implementing listeners.(Assuming that this is happening over the same thread.) Code will look something like this.

Your SDK Implementation class

```
public class SdkImplementation {

    SDK obj = new SDK();
    //listener
    private OnInitializedListener mListener;
    
    //cunstructor initializes the listener
    public SdkImplementation(MainActivity listener) {
        //This check will make sure that the listening class in fact implements the interface
        try {
            //initialize the listener
            mListener = (OnInitializedListener) listener;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(listener.toString()
                    + " must implement OnInitializedListener");
        }
    }


    public void initialise(Context context) {
        obj.initialise(context);

        /**
         * after finishing initialization, call the listener method.
         * you can also pass data if you change the signature*/
        mListener.onInitialized();
    }


    public Params getParams() {
        return obj.getParameters();
    }

    //listener interface
    public interface OnInitializedListener {
        //Change the method signature as per your requirement
        public void onInitialized();
    }

}
```

Now, from wherever you are calling(I have assumed here it as an activity)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SdkImplementation.OnInitializedListener  {

    private SdkImplementation sdkImplementation = SdkImplementation(this)

    @override
    onCreate(......) {
        //Do stuff.....
        //call sdk initialization
        sdkImplementation.initialise();
    }

    @override 
    public void onInitialized() {
        Params params = sdkImplementation.getParams()
        //do whatever you want to do with params
    }
}
```

I see that you have implemented two classes and listening to params at both places. If it is a must to have flow as per your SDK implementation, add another listener same like this inside your Bridge class and replicate the same pattern.

If your scenario is happening on separate threads, you will have to implement some message passing mechanism between threads.

Comment: Initialise is an Asynchronous method. I need to wait after helper.initialise(context) is called for initialisation to complete and then move to the next line, helper.getParams which gets us some object which has to be returned (return type of getParams is Params) and is passed in some api calls later.

Comment: @Sarthak, This solution(The listener) is exactly designed for such scenarios.

Comment: In the solution proposed above, the main thread will go on executing the onInitialise method even before the Initialisation is completed because Initialisation works on a background thread!!

Comment: Main thread is not executing initialization. According to you 'obj.initialise(context)' initializes the sdk(an asynchronous call by sdk, I assume). So the main thread will wait until the sdk finishes initialization.